# Permanent app tile on home screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm creating an app for a limited audience inside my company.

I'd like to have an icon or tile (icon + text) which remains on the home screen (on top of other things) which will allow people to come back to my app.

Something like this:

[image: app tile on home screen]

Is it possible to program something similar?

Comment: Well you can create a `Widget` to display something on the Home screen for sure, however I'm not sure there's an option to have it on top of everything else. More info on widget at http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html

Comment: It's simple enough using a system alert window, but I'm not sure obscuring the status bar is a good idea.

Comment: I ended up using a system alert window. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a system alert window.

Just in case anyone is interested in doing the same thing - here's the code:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity=Gravity.TOP;

TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Touch to return to my app");

wm.addView(view, params);
```

Thanks!